# Is it necessary to check whether a pointer is null before free()

Tags: c, pointers, memory-management, struct, free

Ì used to make sure a pointer was not null before freeing it, so I would normally destroy dynamically created structs like this:

```
Node *destroy_node(Node *node) {
    if (node) {
        free(node);
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

But [CERT MEM34](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/c/MEM34-C.+Only+free+memory+allocated+dynamically) suggests that since free() accepts null pointers, I could as well write

```
Node *destroy_node(Node *node) {
    free(node);
    return NULL;
}
```

Is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, passing `NULL` (a null-pointer constant) to `free()` is perfectly valid.

Quoting `C11`, chapter §7.22.3.3, (*emphasis mine*)

> The `free` function causes the space pointed to by `ptr` to be deallocated, that is, made
>   available for further allocation. **If `ptr` is a null pointer, no action occurs.** [...]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, passing `NULL` to `free` is a no-op.

Excerpt from n1570 (C11 final draft):

> 7.22.3.3 The free function
>   Synopsis
>   1 #include  void free(void *ptr);
>   Description
>   2 The free function causes the space pointed to by ptr to be deallocated, that is, made available for further allocation. If ptr is a null pointer, no action occurs. Otherwise, if the argument does not match a pointer earlier returned by a memory management function, or if the space has been deallocated by a call to free or realloc, the behavior is undeﬁned.
>   Returns
>   3 The free function returns no value.